# How to map same static resource to all urls in micronaut?

Tags: .htaccess, micronaut

I am working micronaut project. I want to serve UI pages from micronaut server. Whenever any page is requested, I want to serve index.html file which is on the root of the static resource folder

Is there any .htaccess equivalent file in micronaut?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any .htaccess equivalent file in micronaut?

No there isn't.